# Ember Data DS.model's set() not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model set for a route like so:

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        myModel = this.store.find('user', 1);
        return myModel;
    },
});
```

The model binds to values in a form. The "update" action is supposed to submit the form, updating the model:

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        update: function() {
            var user = this.get('model');
            var data = this.getProperties('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'userName', 'password', 'confirmPassword');
            user.set('userName', data['userName']);
            user.set('firstName', data['firstName']);
            user.set('lastName', data['lastName']);
            user.set('email', data['email']);
            if (data['password']) {
                if (data['password'] == data['confirmPassword']) {
                    user.set('password', data['password']);
                } else {
                    this.setProperties({error: {'confirmPassword': 'Passwords must match.'}});
                }
            }
            console.log(user);
            if (!this.get('error')) {
                user.save();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However the call to `console.log(user)` reveals that the model has not been set with the new values. I can also try setting the values inline in the code (i.e. not depending on the form bindings) and still no dice. What gives?

Comment: Are you on the settings route?

Comment: When you get model do you get 'user' or do you get 'settings' object? Are you sure that user has all required properties and that data has information in it. Can you try small piece of code - just setting one property with hardcoded value on user and having output before and after.